# How to render Karate.Config values in Scenario outline

Tags: karate

I am just wondering if there is a way to make use of karate.config values in Scenario Outline statement. Please have a look at the example below:

```
Feature: Sample feature

Scenario Outline: Sample scenario for id: <id>
  

Examples:
| id        |
| partnerId |
```

Here the **partnerId** is defined in Karate.config file (just say it is '123'). When I run the file I want to see '123' in scenario outline in reports rather than the value holder 'partnerId'
[image: Sample report image]

Expected:
[image: Expected report]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking for variables to be able to be substituted into the title. Sorry, that's not supported. You can always `print` these values so they will show in the HTML report, but yes - not as the title.